# Noise cancellation?

Tags: sound, skype

I'm  looking for a way to cancel out the noise of my mechanical keyboard in skype chat. After looking through skype settings and the sound settings gui, I did not find a setting for noise cancelation. I did however find an option for echo reduction, which is not what I need. Does anyone know of a way I can filter out this annoying keyboard noise?

Comment: You could look into getting a better mic, maybe something unidirectional/cardioid and closer to your face. Or a mic that includes noise cancellation.

Comment: There isn't even keyclick noise cancelling software for Windows and gaming, possibly because it's in the same frequency range as human voice ie 80 to 250 hz. I still don't think this is a Ubuntu question and off-topic. That said there are lots of tips on google for reducing keyboard click sounds via mic positioning, placing towel under keyboard, reducing mic gain, putting mic closer to mouth, etc.

Comment: Jawbone Bluetooth headsets can cancel out all background noise.  Just something to look into:  http://www.ehow.com/how-does_4673191_jawbone-bluetooth-headset-work.html